# Automatic break lines on a list

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Let's say im getting info from an api and show it on my html view as list, but each value inside of a box.

Per example:

```
    <ul ng-repeat="list on lists" class="inline">
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li>Four</li>
        <li>Five</li>
    </ul>
```

On CSS:

```
li {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

What i want to do is to add an automatic break line between two values. No matter the quantity of values, every two records i need a break line to have something like this:

```
<ul ng-repeat="list on lists">
            <li>One</li>
            <li>Two</li>
            <br>
            <li>Three</li>
            <li>Four</li>
            <br>
            <li>Five</li>
        </ul>
```

How can i do that? I've tried using `white-space` with not success. Also, i've tried limit the space with bootstrap card, and it works a little, but the header of the third (and the next boxes) stay very close with the footer of the first two.

I'm using AngularJs and Javascript.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Are you sure you need to insert `<br>` elements, or are you simply looking to insert space? If the former, you may want to re-think your strategy as this content is not permitted directly inside a [`<ul>` (mdn link)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul). If the latter, you can use CSS, something like `:nth-child(even)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you should utilize the modulus of 2 === 0. Create a class for `.break` and add the appropriate class to have it break.  You may not want to use `ul` you may want to use the `:after` selector to add a div with `display:block; content:""` property.  The `<li>` tags should be `inline-block` if you do go the `ul` route.

```
<ul ng-repeat="list on lists" class="inline">
    <li ng-class="{'break': $index % 2 === 0 }">{{ list.key}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `$index` angular variable and an `ng-if` on a `<li>` tag like this:

```
    <ul ng-repeat="item in data">
        <li ng-if="$index !== 0 && $index % 2 === 0">&nbsp;</li>
        <li>{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
```

As it was pointed out in a few comments, MDN only permits nested lists inside of lists, and not technically `<br>`.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tgtn3ckf/)

Comment: @georgeawg, making a list item with `&nbsp;` works the same as well, and seems to conform to MDN standard. - updated answer